# UK GDP: What does B-E mean?

Tags: finance

[This time series](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/timeseries/k27q/diop?referrer=search&searchTerm=k27q) from the Office for National Statistics is entitled

> B-E: PRODUCTION: CVM: annual & monthly gr

CVM means chained volume measure, I've got that. It's B-E I can't figure out. I've looked in [the publication linked to at the bottom of the page](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/bulletins/indexofproduction/november2019), but couldn't find it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The economy of the UK has been divided into sectors:

A is Agriculture, forestry and fishing

B - E (that is B,C,D,E) are various sectors that Manufacture or Produce goods

F is Construction

G - T (that is G through T) are various Services sectors

I found this information in https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/methodologies/outputapproachtogrossdomesticproductgdp

MOre detailed breakdown of what industries are in various sectors (and subsectors) can be found in this document https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/economy/economicoutputandproductivity/output/methodologies/indexofproductioniop/aguidetotheindexofproduction.pdf